# How to integrate NetSuite API in PHP

Tags: php, joomla, netsuite

Is Possible to integrate NetSuite API in Joomla. Please Give Any suggestion for this Integration.

I Already Tried. But It's Failed to Integration

Comment: Ask specific programming questions with relevant codes only on StackOverflow !

Comment: What did you try? What is failing? More specific questions will help us help you better. There are several ways to integrate with NetSuite.

Comment: @egrubaugh360,say some way to integrate  netsuite

Comment: As TonyH mentioned in his answer, you can use the PHP SDK, you can build RESTlets, or you can use NetSuite's SOAP Web Services directly.

Answer (score 3):

Since Joomla is PHP based, and there is a NetSuite SDK in PHP, it's entirely doable and I've done some small scale projects this way. Ignoring the SDK, you could also setup some NetSuite RESTlets to send and receive the data you want in some convenient format like JSON.

Comment: I'm about to work on a NS/PHP prject, do you happen to have any example projects I could take a look at, or know where I could find one?